# Return JSON with object mapper, choosen by me

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have my custom `ObjectMapper`, that configured in the following way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan({"xxx.service", "xxx.controller" })
public class SpringWebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

........

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setObjectMapper(jacksonMapper());
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public MyOwnMapper jacksonMapper(){
        return new MyOwnMapper();
    }

}
```

So far as i know, `@ResponseBody` automaticaly uses some default `ObjectMapper`. In my case default `ObjectMapper` is `MyOwnMapper`. But what I have to do, if in some method with `@ResponseBody`, I wanna use other `ObjectMapper`(for example, standart `ObjectMapper` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` package)? I have tried write something like

```
@RequestMapping("/card")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map card(@RequestParam int id) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper(); 
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(cardService.getCommonInfo(id));
    }
```

but then my method returns simple string, not JSON.

Comment: Then change your method to have a return type of `String`. You'll have to manually change the `Content-Type` to `application/json`.

Comment: add @Produces(MediaType.APPICATION_JSON) and try with string as return type

Comment: @VivekSingh Are we in JAX-RS or Spring MVC?

Comment: @Produces is supported in JAX-RS

Comment: I've added `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON` to `@RequestMapping`, but it's doesn't work.

Comment: @VivekSingh OP isn't using JAX_RS.